# How to get an object printed?

Tags: arraylist, printing, tostring

```
System.out.println(savedOrder.orderSoftware.get(0).getOrder().toString());
```

Keep getting results like this: 
    [Ljava.lang.Object;@131a30d
    [Ljava.lang.Object;@131a30d
    [Ljava.lang.Object;@131a30d
    [Ljava.lang.Object;@131a30d

Answer (score 1):

You have to override toString method or write another method which writes variables to human-readable format.

There is no automatic way to print human-readable instances of non-primitive types (like Order in your case)

Comment: public class Orders
{
    private static Object[] ordered = new Object[100];

    public Orders(Object[] ordered)
    {
        this.ordered = ordered;
    }
    
    public void setOrder(Object[] ordered)
    {
        this.ordered = ordered;
    }
    
    public Object[] getOrder()
    {
        return ordered;
    }
    
    @Override
   public String toString() {
        return ("ORDERS"+this.getOrder());
   }
    
    /*public String toString()
    {
        return ordered.toString();
    }*/
    
}but still getting the same result